# Invoke-WebRequest GetSystemWebProxy()

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Under PowerShell 2.0 I know that you can set the proxy you would like to use without knowing the exact proxy settings by doing something like the following:

```
$proxy = [System.Net.WebRequest]::GetSystemWebproxy()
$proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
```

Now, my question is if I don't know the proxy settings can I use the above and combine it with a PowerShell 3.0 `Invoke-WebRequest`. Here's what I was hoping to be able to do:

```
$proxy = [System.Net.WebRequest]::GetSystemWebproxy()
$proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials

$WS.Proxy = $proxy

$login = Invoke-WebRequest https://website.com/login_form.html -SessionVariable WS
```

However, when I attempt to do this I get an error, (apparently from my company proxy) indicating that my credentials cannot be verified. I'm hoping that this will ultimately work, but perhaps I'm just making a simple mistake.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Maybe this can help, I keep it in my profile. It is using the new the `$PSDefaultParameterValues` preference variable to set the default proxy values for the new web cmdlets. The code detects if I'm in my office environment and set the settings accordingly. This saves me specifying the settings each time I use those commands.

```
if(Test-Connection myCorpProxy -Count 1 -Quiet)
{
    $global:PSDefaultParameterValues = @{
        'Invoke-RestMethod:Proxy'='http://myCorpProxy:8080'
        'Invoke-WebRequest:Proxy'='http://myCorpProxy:8080'
        '*:ProxyUseDefaultCredentials'=$true
    }
}
```

Comment: i hadn't thought about fixing it this way...but that's pretty crafty and useful in a lot of scenarios.  but if they create new commands....

Answer (score 14):

Use can use this code :

```
$dest = "http://www.google.fr"
$proxyurl = ([System.Net.WebRequest]::GetSystemWebproxy()).GetProxy($dest)
Invoke-WebRequest $dest -Proxy $proxyurl -ProxyUseDefaultCredentials
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem with your code above (even though Shay's is more elegant) is that you're trying to set a property on a variable before it exists.  The SessionVariable "$WS" doesn't exist before you call Invoke-WebRequest but you're trying to set the .Proxy property above it.

If it worked at one point, you had probably created an instance of $WS previously and therefore were able to work with the object during testing but on a fresh/dry run when the script was processing top-down, it didn't yet exist.