# Cloning repository using GIT on Powershell ISE - Proxy issues

Tags: git, powershell, http, proxy, azure-devops

I am getting proxy errors using PowerShell ISE with Git-Posh.

When using GIT only (Bash), cloning goes fine. I had to add these to the .gitconfig file

```
[http]
    proxy = http://localhost:1800

[https]
    proxy = http://localhost:1800
```

However, when using Git-posh on a PowerShell ISE script I get exceptions:

1) Command one generates this exception.

```
$resp = Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $headers -Uri ("{0}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=1.0" -f $url)
$json = convertFrom-JSON $resp.Content
```

> Invoke-WebRequest : Proxy Authorization Required
>       Description: Authorization is required for access to this proxy

2) Cloning generates this exception

```
 git clone --mirror $url
```

> fatal: unable to access
>   'https://pn%fastCars.onmicrosoft.com:3kfokgwgwgwiigjiwjgjwigiiqegqegewrwghdasdasfggaffaa@fastCars.visualstudio.com/Ferrari/_git/FerrariF50-PerformanceTests/':
>   Failed to
>        connect to localhost port 1800: Connection refused

Does anyone know which command can turn this around?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15646079/1630171). [Related](https://gist.github.com/evantoli/f8c23a37eb3558ab8765).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just use straight powershell to work with Git you can use this [module to work with VSTS online](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/VSTS/1.0.189). In order to be able to authenticate to VSTS online I had to get a [Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate).  Once I got my token and authenticated with it, I then was able to use the cmdlets in the VSTS module.